# Specman e : Conditional Constraint in config sequence

Tags: specman, e

In the config sequence I would like to create a conditional constraint. I have two clock rates and only a set of combinations of the clock rates are legal in the design.

I am having trouble coming up with the correct syntax to achieve this.The use of case or if statements give me a syntax error. This is what I have right now.

```
case main_clk{
    1e6:{
        keep div_clk == select{
            80: 5e9;
            20: 5.6e9;
        };
    };
   .
   .
   .
};
```

I also tried using `when` but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I see from you using scientific notation from your numbers that you are using `real` fields. You should probably switch to using `uint` fields as they are more flexible from a generation point of view.

The `case` statement is procedural and cannot be used for generation. The same goes for `if`. To generate a field conditionally on the other you need to use the `=>` (implication) operator:

```
  keep main_clk == 1e6 =>
    soft div_clk == select {
      80: 5e9;
      20: 5.6e9;
    };
```

You need one such implication for each possible value of `main_clk`.